# Reallocation of shared memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have a question about the CUDA C++ programming. I am using shared memory. But I need larger shared memory. So I was trying to reuse the shared memory. My code is like:

```
__global__ void dist_calculation(...){

   ..........
   {
        //1st pass
       __shared__ short unsigned int shared_nodes[(number_of_nodes-1)*blocksize];

       ............

   }

   {
       //2nd pass
       __shared__ float s_distance_matrix[(number_of_nodes*(number_of_nodes-1))/2];

       ........
   }
}
```

Shared memory can't accommodate both `shared_nodes` and `s_distance_matrix` together. But it can accommodate each separately (I have tested). In the 2nd pass, the program can't recognize  `shared_nodes` (as it is from 1st pass), but shows me an error that the shared memory doesn't have enough space. So it looks like, some space is still allocated for the `shared_nodes` variable. Is there any way to destroy that allocation (like `cudaFree`)? or any other suggestions?

Comment: If 1st pass function and 2nd pass function are not related to each other, you can try separating those functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allocate a single untyped buffer large enough to accommodate either array and reinterpret the array for each pass of your algorithm:

```
__global__ void dist_calculation(...)
{
   const unsigned int num_bytes1 = sizeof(unsigned short) * (number_of_nodes-1) * block_size;

   const unsigned int num_bytes2 = sizeof(float) * (number_of_nodes) * (number_of_nodes-1)) / 2;

   const unsigned int num_shared_bytes = num_bytes1 > num_bytes2? num_bytes1: num_bytes2;

   __shared__ char smem[num_shared_bytes]; 

   unsigned short *shared_nodes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(smem);
   first_pass(shared_nodes);

   float *distance_matrix = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(smem);
   second_pass(distance_matrix);    
}
```